# How to ensure data consistency and truly take advantage of Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I've worked on several iOS apps, some of them utilize Core Data, and some of them don't. While I consider myself having a basic to somewhat good understanding of Core Data, there's always something that makes me doubt the usefulness of it. I've done a lot of reading on the subject, and the general consensus seems to be the advantages of using it outweighs the disadvantages. I recently submitted an app without using Core Data, and always planned on going back to update the project to utilize it when I have the time for some optimization work. Now's the time, but I wonder if it makes sense for the app I'm working on, and maybe I am not using it correctly all along. Please advise and point out what I am missing.

The project I am working on is a social networking app, which also has a front-end site. We have standard features like a newsfeed, event listing, the ability to follow/unfollow someone, and a map with POIs at user's location. Currently, we're using pagination whenever needed when requesting data from server.

My understanding of why Core Data is great:

- Easier to manage data with complicated relationship
- Easier to access data without having to pass them around
- Easier to manipulate, fetch, and sort your data
- Better memory utilization
- Improve perceived performance by preloading data stored locally until latest data's received

The problem I am having is, since I am using pagination when requesting for data instead of requesting for all at once. The data stored locally is only a subset of the current state in the database. Let's use newsfeed as an example. If I do the following, it will cause some problems:

- User manually refresh the newsfeed -> Controller notifies model that it needs the latest 20 items -> Model requests for the latest 20 items in the newsfeed and save them as NSManagedObject -> Model notifies controller that data is ready -> Fetch the latest 20 items to show in UITableView

If user A refreshes the newsfeed, background the app, and then user B deletes his post in the newsfeed (let's say it was 10th item) before user A foregrounds the app again to refresh the newsfeed. In user A's newsfeed, B's post will still be up there because according to the createdAt attribute, it's indeed one of the latest 20 items.

To fix this problem, I can think of a few solutions:

1. Add a flag to the item to indicate it's removed
2. Always discard local data when new data arrives
3. Disable pagination
4. Instead of using the workflow described above, always present the requested data only instead of fetching the latest

Solution 1 means custom code is required to deal with different clients since browser doesn't need deleted items but iOS client does. However, even though it can work, it can potentially mess up the pagination mechanism and can cause weird behaviours in the client. For example, if a large amount of items gets removed, the latest 20 items will contain only a few items that will actually show up in the newsfeed on the client when user refreshes it. As user follows more people, more stories will be inserted in his newsfeed as well. This solution won't work very well in this situation.

Solution 2 totally defeats the purpose of using Core Data in the first place unless I am missing something.

Solution 3 means the client always needs to request for all data. This is nearly impossible to do because as you get more data, the time to retrieve and process them will make the app slow and unresponsive. It also doesn't make sense from technical and UX point of view.

Solution 4 also kinda defeats the purpose of using Core Data because it's the same workflow when we only store data in memory. You can still fetch and find objects but they might be invalid on the server already at the time of access.

Am I missing something? How is Core Data supposed to be used in this scenario? How do you ensure data consistency when the client doesn't have all the data? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Only the server can have a consistent view of the data in the use cases you are describing, and the server (should) be sending you freshness information along with the response. Attempting to maintain a consistent view of the data on the device is extremely challenging, and may not be possible given the constraints of your data - wether you use Core Data or some other method of on-device persistence your problems will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It then makes me wonder why and how people are using it. I always feel like I am missing something. If not, then are people just using it for offline access and data preloading alone? For an app that's small enough, memory usage shouldn't be a problem anyway.

Comment: I could give you the long version, but the short version is that often they're using Core Data as a local cache because they do not understand the protocols they are using. The URL loading system already supports offline access, and the HTTP protocol provides freshness which when used correctly on the server side ensures consistency. If the server side API is poorly designed, there isn't anything you can do on the client to solve it. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: You forgot to mention model versioning and automatic model migration as of the advantages:)

Comment: As an aside we flag our content with a isInTrash property and when its no longer on the server we set this to TRUE, then the user can keep reading it but on the next app launch we delete everything in trash. This prevents those nasty crashes when accessing an MO after its been deleted.